# Capture Identifiable Info With jQuery or SQL

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server

We have a legacy asp.net application that is used inside our network. Unfortunately, security and logging was not built into the application. Users must be added to an AD group in order to get to the web application folder.

We believe that a user is purposefully trying to discredit another employee by assigning records to them that they are not aware of.

We have the source code for the application, but I'm afraid that what we have is not what is actually used in production. I'm hoping that I can find a solution that will not involve the recompiling of the web application

I've looked into jQuery for trying to capture lan ip addresses, but from what I have read, this does not seem possible.

I have also tried to capture identifiable information with a stored procedure whenever a record is saved or updated. So far everything that I have tried to capture has been related to the server and not the client's computer. This application runs on SQL Server 2000.

For what it's worth, all users of the application must use IE.

Is anyone aware of a way to acomplish this using jQuery or SQL Server?

Comment: jQuery runs on the client. Sql Server runs on the database server. Your best bet would be the web server. Or if you have suspicions about a particular employee, then start logging their web traffic or recording their screen.

Comment: I think your are correct.